# How to add type annotations for Into for the iterator element of a vector?

Tags: vector, rust, annotations, traits

I have a vector whose values are trait defined and I would like to use the methods provided by the `Iterator` trait on this vector.

Here is an simplified code of my use case:

#### Case A

```
fn beta<T: Into<i32>>(s: Vec<T>) {
    for x in s {
        println!("{:?}", x.into());
    }
}
```

#### Case B

```
fn beta2<U: Into<i32>>(s: Vec<U>) {
    for x in s.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", x.into());
    } 
}
```

*Case A* is valid and compiles and runs as expected. *Case B* however will raise a compile time error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:11:26
   |
11 |         println!("{:?}", x.into());
   |                          ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

Where should I place my type annotation in this case and what's the expected type annotation?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3d46a0b35d7643040c8920e7dc9f64b1)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to inform `beta2` that `&U` (as opposed to `U`) implements `Into<i32>`:

```
fn beta2<U>(s: Vec<U>)
where
    for<'a> &'a U: Into<i32>,
{
    for x in s.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", x.into());
    }
}
```

Note that `Into` accepts `self` and not `&self`, i.e. it consumes its argument. Thus, you would have to find some way to convert the borrowed `x` into an owned value:

```
fn beta2<U, U2>(s: Vec<U>)
where
    U: std::borrow::ToOwned<Owned = U2>,
    U2: Into<i32> + std::borrow::Borrow<U>,
{
    for x in s.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", x.to_owned().into());
    }
}
```

Comment: The first snippet gives an error: ```the trait `for<'a> std::convert::From<&'a _>` is not implemented for `i32````

Comment: @mattgathu You are right. But note that the error is not originating from within `beta2`, but from the call site. The problem is that `x` is borrowed (i.e. it is of type `&u8`), but `Into` expects an owned value (i.e. `u8`).

Comment: *`&U` (as opposed to `U`)* — You should explain to the OP why this difference is needed in this case.

Comment: What's the point of going to this trouble if `beta2` consumes the vector anyway?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I assumed that the "real" code wants to iterate over it twice.

Comment: Instead of using `.iter()` it's more idiomatic to pass the vector as a slice: `fn beta2<U, U2>(s: &[U])`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your exact use case is, but I would generally assume that types that are `Into<u32>` can be cloned and are cheap to clone, so I think the easiest solution is

```
fn beta2<U: Clone + Into<i32>>(s: &[U]) {
    for x in s.iter().cloned() {
        println!("{:?}", x.into());
    }
}
```

This will clone each element before calling `.into()` on it, which will consume the clone.

Note that I have changed the argument `s` to a slice.  If you are consuming the vector anyway by taking it by value, there is no harm in using the code from your first example, so this only makes sense if you take a slice by reference.